# Aiogram Telegram Python бот

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

подскажите новичку как передать данные админу группы, или по определенному ID данные что заполнил пользователь. Идея такая человек заполняет данные, после данные нужно переслать админу группы, вопрос именно как продублировать итоговую информацию админу группы.[image: Как передать это сообщение админу группы?]

Comment: в данном виде вопрос не очень понятен и не совсем понятно что вам отвечать... те данные которые заполняет пользователь...куда они уходят? в никуда?.. для начала положите заполненные данные куда-нибудь в базу или еще какое хранилище. После заполнения, можете их оттуда извлекать и присылать администратору. В чем именно возникает сложность?

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html код брал из шаблона, как понимаю тут создается ячейка памяти, вопрос как передать данные админу из памяти или переслать сообщение что получает пользователь по итогу заполнение формы.

Comment: @Belwer31 приведите свой код